# How to make sure images are responsive and same height?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

I want to make sure the images in my site are responsive, and stay the same height when the window size is reduced. I have a media query that changed the layout to 1 column instead of two on smaller screens, but on large screens the image heights are not the same. I've put all of the images into divs and limited the size of those divs, but nothing I'm doing seems to be changing the image heights so that they stay responsive. I've tried using object-fit and flexbox but nothing seems to be working.

Site is here: https://giagnus64.github.io/mineight-site/

Comment: You could put them in a container, give the container a height, and then set your `img` tags to be height: 100%. Alternatively, you may be insterested in [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)  Edit: Just saw you tried flexbox, but will leave the link for others

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using your existing images if you modified your HTML and used background images instead of inline images.

The easier solution though would simply be to make all your images exactly the same size. Most of them are 690px wide x 460px high, so if you resize and crop the ones that are giving you a hard time to 690px x 460px all will be good.

Instead of resizing, you could also crop the images to the equivalent aspect ratio of 690:460. This will work provided the images are still wide enough to cover your .feature-box div at every viewport.

Good luck!